# How not to overwhelm "Resources" or Memory Space in Browser?

Tags: javascript, caching, memory, browser, resources

I built a website using HTML/JavaScript that successively loads a total of 300 short videos. I've found, however, that some computers can't handle that much in their browser -- Is there a way to have my code avoid filling up the browser Resources with these videos? Also, is "Resources" (as defined in Safari 7) the same as Memory Space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend loading the video thumbnails first, and when a User clicks one to then replace the thumbnail with the video. This would reduce the cost of loading up the page, since not all of the videos are loading up at once, unless you intend on all of them to play simultaneously.

Comment: I've actually done that @Tsaukpaetra, and the loading part works fine. The problem I have is with all the videos saving to the memory space one at a time (as the user clicks "Next" to view the next video) until halfway into the videos, the next video suddenly can't load anymore because the memory space is full.

Comment: @user3263954: Remove the old videos when they're finished to save memory.

Comment: Yes, before ajaxing the video clicked, you could clear out any existing video divs.